# Convert a JRuby project running on TC server /Tomcat to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jruby, war

I currently have a project running on JRuby which is packaged in a WAR and deployed on TC Server / tomcat.

I was looking into spring boot and I am wondering if someone can explain how easy / hard it would be to convert that application to run on Spring Boot on JRuby.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question may not be worded the best, but being sarcastic is neither helpful nor a great welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry! It was not meant to be sarcastic. Don't worry if I didn't find the question. Further readers may understand your question better.

Comment: apologies for jumping to conclusions then :)

Answer (score 0):

.war is packed up as "standard" JavaEE project (see the generated *web.xml*) - nothing fancy really.

that means that you could add whatever libraries and additional files as you want as long as you understand the [JRuby-Rack](http://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack) bootup process. your question is kind of vague as of how Spring should interact with JRuby or if it won't need to interact at all. if not simply add another context listener to boot spring, include the spring .jar files and map the URL handling accordingly.